# Are default automatic created partitions too small? Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: freeze, system, partitioning, default

I reinstalled new clean version of Ubuntu 17.04 onto my computer.
This is single OS on this computer so I use "Erase disc and install Ubuntu" without manual creation of partitions...

Everything it seems fine but partitions by default seem to small? Just 500MB!

[image]

Please see screenshot how my hard looks now!  How does it possible by default?
Sometimes it freezing... :-(

Please help,

Sinisa

Comment: 500 MB for the EFI partition is just fine, this one only contains few and small files. The /boot partition *could* be bigger, but here 500 MB should also normally be enough unless you pile up old kernel images.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, it is good to know this...  This is my second installation of Ubuntu... At first I was created two bigger partititons manuallly according with some tutorial... But now I just overwrite through installation wizard.

Comment: Oh, and no, this can not be a reason for any freezing. If anything, you would get disk-full-errors when trying to install kernel updates. Other than that there should not be any possible trouble a full or too small /boot partition could cause.

Comment: Full disks don’t normally cause *system* crashes (*application* crashes are a different thing).

Answer (score 1):

These small partitions are boot partitions. As you can see they only use 4,4 [Mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) or rather 152,2 MiB, around 500 MiB of size is totally fine for them.

So: **No**, the automatically created partitions are perfectly good the way they are.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for answer... It seemed weird to me that installation wizard colud produce such big mistake by defalut, or  which can be a reason why my new Ubuntu freezies time to time so soon after installation... I thought  maybe small partitions could be a reason. My Ubuntu 16.04 never freezed up before... Can be some bug in new 17.04 version?

Comment: @SinišaBotaš Please search for your symptoms in other questions and –
 if necessary – pose a new one for that, giving us exact information, error outputs etc. It' simpossible to say this way.